# Make shapes drawn on canvas unmovable(fabric.js)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have started using `fabric.js` today for drawing on my canvas using different modes. That means when I click *lines* button I shall be able to draw straight lines on canvas. When I press *rectangles*  button I shall be able to draw rectangles and same with *freehand* button. I am able to draw all of them.

Problem comes here. Once I draw any shape and try to draw some thing else near the old shape, the previous shape is becoming movable.

Here is my code

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #myCanvas { background:url("images/<s:property value="userImageFileName"/>") ;
                 background-size: 100% 100%;
                 background-repeat: no-repeat;}
    </style>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fabric.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jscolor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="result" src="images/<s:property value="userImageFileName"/>" hidden="true" width="565" height="584" class="annotatable"/>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="565" height="584" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">Please use a modern browser like Firefox, Chrome, Safari</canvas>

    <div >Choose Color</div>
    <input class="color" id="selectedColor">

    <input type="button" value="rectangles" onClick="operate('rectangles')">
    <input type="button" value="freehand"   onClick="operate('freehand')">
    <input type="button" value="lines"      onClick="operate('lines')">
    <input type="submit" value="save"       onClick="save()">
    <br>
    <canvas id="canvas2" width="565" height="584"></canvas>
    <img id="canvasImg" alt="No annotated image found">

    <script>
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas', { selection: false });
        var drawRectangle = false;
        var color;

        function operate(mode)
        {
            var line, mouseClicked = false;

            canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o)
            {
                mouseClicked = true;
                var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
                color=document.getElementById("selectedColor").value;

                if(mode=="freehand")
                {
                    canvas.isDrawingMode    = true;
                    drawRectangle           = false;

                    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 5;
                    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = '#'+color;
                }

                else if(mode=="lines")
                {
                    canvas.isDrawingMode    = false;
                    drawRectangle           = false;

                    var points = [ pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y ];
                    line = new fabric.Line(points, {
                        strokeWidth: 5,
                        fill: 'red',
                        stroke: 'red',
                        originX: 'center',
                        originY: 'center'
                    });
                    canvas.add(line);
                }

                else if(mode=="rectangles")
                {
                    canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
                    drawRectangle = true;

                    origX = pointer.x;
                    origY = pointer.y;
                    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
                    rect = new fabric.Rect({
                        left: origX,
                        top: origY,
                        originX: 'left',
                        originY: 'top',
                        width: pointer.x-origX,
                        height: pointer.y-origY,
                        angle: 0,
                        transparentCorners: false,
                        stroke: "red",
                        fill:"transparent",
                        strokeWidth: 5
                    });
                    canvas.add(rect);
                }

            });

            canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o)
            {
                if (!mouseClicked) return;
                var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);

                if(mode=="lines")
                {
                      line.set({ x2: pointer.x, y2: pointer.y });
                      canvas.renderAll();
                }

                else if(mode=="rectangles")
                {
                     if(origX>pointer.x){
                        rect.set({ left: Math.abs(pointer.x) });
                     }
                     if(origY>pointer.y){
                        rect.set({ top: Math.abs(pointer.y) });
                     }

                     rect.set({ width: Math.abs(origX - pointer.x) });
                     rect.set({ height: Math.abs(origY - pointer.y) });

                     canvas.renderAll();
                }

            });

            canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
              mouseClicked = false;
            });
        }

        function save(){
            var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
            var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

            var img=document.getElementById("result");
            context2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 565, 584);
            context2.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);

            var canvasData = canvas2.toDataURL();
            //document.write(dataURL);
            document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = canvasData;

        };

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also I am getting problem with saving the canvas as image. The `saving` code in the given code is my old code which was working fine before I switched to `fabric.js`.

[image: In the image You can see the outline of the shape which is allowing me to move that shape.,but I don't want that. How can I get rid of it.]In the image You can see the outline of the shape which is allowing me to move that shape.,but I don't want that. How can I get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it may seem a tad expensive, but consider setting all other objects on the canvas to have their `selectable` or `evented` property set to `false`. Doing so will ensure that none that they won't react to any mouse input while you're drawing.

`selectable` controls if the object can be physically selected, while `evented` prevents it from reacting with any events whatsoever.

As far as your `save()` function, it looks as if you are accessing the `toDataURL()` method of the regular HTML5 Canvas API. That may seem to work, but remember that fabric uses **two** canvas elements behind-the-scenes. You likely wouldn't be getting the full image. use the `toDataURL` method of your `fabric.Canvas` instance that you declared at the top of your code, and that should be all you need. You won't need to find the `context` of the canvas or anything like that either.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I stopped using fabric because at the end of the day I came to know, there is no eraser in fabric and is difficult to write it as well as saving it.